# Save form input into file to be extracted with Node-Red

Tags: input, save, node-red

I'm trying to create a page, with help of Node-Red, that shows a feed (extracted from the search results of Dribbble) of images. I'm currently so far that it can show items from Dribbble with a pre-set query. Now the search results (feed) should be variable, in such way you can choose the tags.

However, I can't seem to find a way to save the tags you are interested in. Let's say I would have a page which contains an `<input>`, whatever you fill in and send would be saved to, let's say, interestingItems.html.

How would I save the 'sent' items to a file? Either by Javascript or with Node-Red.

---

I wouldn't mind that by using `localhost:1880/add?=<query you want to add to the list>` instead of a `form input`. That might be easiar, as I just think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the HTTP Input node in POST mode, to a function to read in the form values, which you can store in the global context then generating your interestingItems page using a mustache template.